# Send attachment with PDF extension but its not working

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a dynamic file and send that to the user in the attachment but after downloading it's not opening.
Showing an error saying "Failed to load PDF
In content, I am sending the required data.
Here is my code

```js
router.get('/file',function(req, res){
  var filename1='invoice.pdf';
  filename1 = encodeURIComponent(filename1);
    var mailOptions={
        to: 'userMail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Speaker Added',
        from: "admin@gmail.com",
        headers: {
            "X-Laziness-level": 1000,
            "charset" : 'UTF-8'
        },
        html: '<p style="color:#0079c1;">Hello'+' '+'My Name'+'</p></br>'
        +'<p style="color:#0079c1;">Thank you for choosing HOWDY.<p></br>'
        +'<p>Click on the link below to activate your account and get redirected to HOWDY</p></br>',
        attachments: [
   
        {   
            'filename':filename1,
             'content': 'data',
             'contentType':'application/pdf',
             'contentDisposition':'attachment'
        }
    ]
        
    }
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'admin@gmail.com', 
            pass: 'admin56789' 
        }
    });
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
           return res.send(error);
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                state:'success',
                message:"Send"
            });
        }
    });
})
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You are sending "data" as content of the file. If you right-click your file, and choose open with notepad (or basic text editor) you'll see.

Nodemailer's attachments expect to receive the data of the file if you use the `content` option. You might prefer to use `path` which can be either the filepath or a URL.

Read more [here](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/).

Your attachment:

```
attachments: [
    {   
        'filename':filename1,
         'content': 'data',
         'contentType':'application/pdf',
         'contentDisposition':'attachment'
    }
]
```

Should be closer to:

```
attachments: [
    {   
        'filename':filename1,

         //Either get filecontent
         'content': filecontent,
         //Or the file full path
         'path':filepath,

         'contentType':'application/pdf',
         'contentDisposition':'attachment'
    }
]
```

Comment: But path is defined when the file exists in that location

Comment: What this error means
code:"ESTREAM"
command:"API"
errno:-4068
syscall:"read"

Comment: couldn't get much information... I'm guessing it can't read from stream?

Comment: Just now I solved that issue.
Using pdfkit I am creating one file and then taking that path and sending it to the email attachment.
But can I send dynamic template instead of text
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('will.pdf'));
doc.text('my text11111')
doc.end();

Comment: You can send anything through attachments. Now, how to use the PDF library is out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Ok, I will search